# Error while adding stateless jsf classes to a JSF project

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, clone, jsf-stateless

Sometimes while running a JSF project on Glassfish 3.0.1, I get this error which also brings the server down. Can anybody explain how to fix this?

Actually I am trying to add [Stateless JSF implementation](http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/) classes to my project. Sometimes it runs fine while sometimes gives out this error. [Here is the source code](https://bitbucket.org/industrieit/stateless-jsf/src/693208a2ebdd/src/main/java/com/industrieit/jsf/stateless/impl/SJSFStatePool.java).

```
INFO: 19:23:47.730 [http-thread-pool-8080(2)] ERROR c.i.jsf.stateless.impl.SJSFStatePool - error force cloning view on postback
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final org.osgi.framework.BundleContext field org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.context to org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:59) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:405) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList:22) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:96) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:355) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList:22) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:96) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:355) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap:21) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:96) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:355) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap:22) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:96) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:355) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:377) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:377) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:404) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.deepClone(com.rits.cloning.Cloner:309) ~[cloning-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.industrieit.jsf.stateless.impl.SJSFStatePool.get(SJSFStatePool.java:80) ~[SJSFStatePool.class:na]
    at com.industrieit.jsf.stateless.impl.SJSFViewHandler.initView(SJSFViewHandler.java:62) [SJSFViewHandler.class:na]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:115) [jsf-impl.jar:2.1.3-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl.jar:2.1.3-FCS]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jsf-api.jar:2.1.3-FCS]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393) [org-netbeans-modules-web-httpmonitor.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at px10.Security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:48) [AuthenticationFilter.class:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98) [web-glue.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91) [web-glue.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231) [web-core.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174) [kernel.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.36]
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_23]
```

.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d897543, pid=7096, tid=4344
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [zip.dll+0x7543]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Rajat\.netbeans\7.0\config\GF3\domain1\hs_err_pid7096.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```